Find the constant $c$ such that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z = 1$
Given $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^n + z^{n-1} + \cdots + z^2 + z^{-n}} + \frac{c}{z-1}$$
We need to determine $c$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed to make $f(z)$ analytic at $z = 1$
If we focus on the second term $\frac{c}{z-1}$ then $f(1) = \infty$ and we know it's not differentiable at $z=1$ so is the obvious choice for $c$ is $0$ ?
However I don't understand how to go about this question.

The only such constant is $0.$

Functions which are undefined at $1$ are not analytic at $1.$

Thank you! I was confused if $c$ depends on $n$ somehow.

$g(z)\equiv z^n+z^{n-1}+\cdots +z^2+z^{-n}$ is a Laurent series centered at $0$.  It's meromorphic.
$f(z)=\frac 1{g(z)}+\frac c{z-1}$ is also meromorphic (the meromorphic functions on a domain actually form a field, as long as no denominators are zero on a connected component).
It's defined and analytic on $0\lt\mid z\mid\lt1.$ But not at $z=1$ unless $c=0,$ in which case it's analytic everywhere but $z=0.$
Remember a meromorphic function is analytic off its singularities.

To verify analyticity, you can also check the CR equations.
